# Jenkins Build failing after integration with Selenium tests

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, build.gradle

Am trying to integrate our Testng Selenium tests into the Jenkins build queue using Build Gradle Test, currently failing with unreachable exception error. Its a freestyle build, with Invoke Gradle Script as the build step. Please find the console output in the below:

Build Gradle file:
[image: Build Gradle]

**

- **Build Failure Logs:**

**
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[QaAutomationWeb] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/Gradle_6.5.1/bin/gradle test
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses

> Task :test

FBMS-Modernization Tests > Regression Tests > com.fbms.test.LoginTest > getDriver FAILED
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException at RemoteWebDriver.java:589
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException at DriverService.java:165
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException at UrlChecker.java:104
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException at SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException at FutureTask.java:205

5 tests completed, 1 failed, 4 skipped

> Task :test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':test'.

> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///var/jenkins_home/workspace/QaAutomationWeb/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

[image]

[image]

[image: Build Step Configuration]